# Stan - find dimensions of an object - lower and upper question

Tags: stan, constraint, rstan

I have a bunch of objects (roughly rectangular) , for some of which I know what their dimesions - `x`, `y`, and `z`, are. From some business logic, I know that the bigger of `x` and `y` is between 0 and 15, and the smaller of `x` and `y` is between 0 and 3. Additionally, `x` and `y` are interchange-able - so the objects can be freely rotated along their vertical axis.

What I want, is to somehow encode this constraint in stan. I tried circumventing this: in the training data, wherever `y` was bigger that `x`, I switched them. However, as you can see in this scatterplot, it did not work (if it had, only the lower-right triangle would have points):
[image: scatterplot of predicted x and y values. Notice that the scales are different, and this is why the main mass of points is not along the 45 degree line]

Is there a way to enforce this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce that the predicted $x$ is greater or equal to the predicted $y$, then you can reparameterize your model to use $y$ and $\delta=x-y$, and constrain $\delta$ to be bounded from below by $0$. Then add a generated quantities block in which you compute the predicted $x$ from the predictions for $y$ and $\delta$.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a problem with the upper limit though? Because if I set the upper limit of beta to be 12, I am overconstraining, when y < 3. Alternatively, I could put 15, and be underconstraining.